# Why is Paramiko so slow when executing commands that are fast?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

```
import paramiko
import ssh

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ssh_host, username=ssh_user, password=ssh_passwd)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('time', timeout=300)
start = time.time()
stdout.readlines()
print(f'elapsed: {time.time() - start}'
```

OUTPUT:

```
elapsed: 1.0629479885101318
```

vs running locally:

```
$ time time

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

vs running python locally

test.py

```
import time
start=time.time()
print(f'elapsed: {time.time() - start}')
```

OUTPUT:

```
$ python3 test.py
elapsed: 7.152557373046875e-07
```

I'm only checking the time for when the command is running, and `time` returns almost immediately, but it still takes >1s to run. That seems extremely long. This is also exclusive of the ssh steup/connection.

**EDIT**:

Metrics on running ssh command directly and RTT:

```
$ ssh remote time 2>&1 | while read line; do echo "`date +'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%N %Y'` $line"; done
Thu Sep 30 12:10:17.045624550 2021
Thu Sep 30 12:10:17.046640382 2021 real 0m0.000s
Thu Sep 30 12:10:17.047518094 2021 user 0m0.000s
Thu Sep 30 12:10:17.048373649 2021 sys  0m0.000s
```

```
$ time ssh remote time 2>&1 | while read line; do echo "`date +'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%N %Y'` $line"; done
Thu Sep 30 12:10:36.694376506 2021
Thu Sep 30 12:10:36.695425964 2021 real 0m0.000s
Thu Sep 30 12:10:36.696347822 2021 user 0m0.000s
Thu Sep 30 12:10:36.697234893 2021 sys  0m0.000s

real    0m0.423s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.005s
```

RTT:

```
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.401/0.405/0.422/0.026 ms
```

ssh -v

```
$ ssh -v remote time 2>&1 | while read line; do echo "`date +'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%N %Y'` $line"; done
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.463403647 2021 OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.464389238 2021 debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user_name/.ssh/config
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.465492970 2021 debug1: /home/user_name/.ssh/config line 11: Applying options for remote
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.466583875 2021 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.467567989 2021 debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.468557630 2021 debug1: Connecting to remote [remote_ip] port 22.
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.469518951 2021 debug1: Connection established.
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.470447401 2021 debug1: identity file /home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa_dev type 1
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.471434362 2021 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.472354732 2021 debug1: identity file /home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa_dev-cert type -1
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.473283013 2021 debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.474141590 2021 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.475110801 2021 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.476174471 2021 debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.477111235 2021 debug1: Authenticating to remote:22 as 'remote_user'
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.478265855 2021 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.479124130 2021 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.480019158 2021 debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.480923242 2021 debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.481849840 2021 debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.482724093 2021 debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.483566928 2021 debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.484479465 2021 debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.485411507 2021 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.486294850 2021 debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:bycBupsIKGtJN4ACVfYRMBl4mahOUFs1Z1tz/V0f71w
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.487238710 2021 debug1: Host 'remote' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.488108414 2021 debug1: Found key in /home/user_name/.ssh/known_hosts:6
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.489027882 2021 debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.489877711 2021 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.490768567 2021 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.491718078 2021 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.492650467 2021 debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.493520701 2021 debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.494433476 2021 debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.524232376 2021 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.525490270 2021 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.526420265 2021 debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.527334026 2021 debug1: No valid Key exchange context
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.528265130 2021 debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.529169019 2021 debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.530080064 2021 No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1075)
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.531015618 2021
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.531907775 2021 debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.532835737 2021 No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1075)
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.533666147 2021
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.534487462 2021 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.535315203 2021 debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa_dev
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.536140209 2021 debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.537081945 2021 debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.538008014 2021 Authenticated to remote ([remote_ip]:22).
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.538923798 2021 debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.539804699 2021 debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.540647666 2021 debug1: Entering interactive session.
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.541469077 2021 debug1: pledge: network
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.548486172 2021 debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.588863420 2021 debug1: Sending environment.
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.590085121 2021 debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.590987535 2021 debug1: Sending command: time
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.879118311 2021
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.880089083 2021 real 0m0.000s
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.880993237 2021 user 0m0.000s
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.881840176 2021 sys  0m0.000s
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.882675893 2021 debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.883488013 2021 debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.884312564 2021 debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.885128132 2021 debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.886031729 2021 Transferred: sent 2864, received 2784 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.886861936 2021 Bytes per second: sent 8309.0, received 8076.9
Thu Sep 30 12:21:21.887709496 2021 debug1: Exit status 0
```

**EDIT 2**:

I ran ssh with `subprocess`, which isn't quite the same but I think it's a decent comparison. It's much slower than the pure shell methods but still about 2x as fast as `paramiko`:

test2.py

```
import subprocess
import time
host = 'remote'
cmd = 'time'
start = time.time()
p = subprocess.Popen(f"ssh {host} {cmd}", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print(p)
print(f'elapsed: {time.time() - start}')
```

```
$ time python3 test2.py
(b'', b'\nreal\t0m0.000s\nuser\t0m0.000s\nsys\t0m0.000s\n')
elapsed: 0.4182932376861572

real    0m0.444s
user    0m0.029s
sys     0m0.011s
```

Comment: Are you aware that you are comparing uncomparable? The `exec_command` involves starting a new shell. Maybe that is what takes so long. Did you try something as simple as `echo foo`? Does it also take 1 second? Actually, for me your code returns 0.17s, against an SSH server in a different country => It's not Paramiko's problem. Did you try something like `ssh -v ssh_user@ssh_host time 2>&1 | while read line; do echo "\`date +'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%N %Y'\` $line"; done` – you might see similar results.

Comment: `exec_command` runs before i start recording the time. from my understanding, `exec_command` launches the thread and the `read_lines()` actually waits for the command to complete. i'll the command you mentioned as well but I am recording after the ssh session has be connected and the command has been started.

Comment: But the shell is started only by the `exec_command`, and imo `exec_command` returns immediately, it does not wait for the shell to start.

Comment: What's the RTT between `localhost` and `ssh_host`?

Comment: This kind of job is what profilers are for. Use one. That said, it's normal and expected for a native Python implementation of heavy math (like cryptography) to be slower than a well-optimized native C alternative, so after you fix the issues making the immediate comparison unrealistic, there will always still be _some_ difference remaining.

Comment: So even `ssh` takes about 0.3s to execute the command (between "12:21:21.540647666 2021 debug1: Entering interactive session" and "12:21:21.887709496 2021 debug1: Exit status 0").

Comment: yes it seems so, but that's still a lot faster than the ~1s we're seeing from `paramiko`